# Batch for loop string comparision

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, comparison

```
SET CLIENTS=blah1:blah2

for %%x in (%CLIENTS::= %) do (
SET client=%%x
echo %client%;
if "%1"==%client% goto end
)
:end
```

I would expect to compare blah1 and %1 first and blah2 and %2 second.
However, the %client% will only be assigned with blah2. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion of variables inside `FOR` loops requires you to **enable delayed expansion** to force variables to be expanded at runtime instead of being expanded when parsed. Read `HELP SET` for more information.

And try changing your code to

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET CLIENTS=blah1:blah2
set CLIENTS=%CLIENTS::= %
for %%x in (%CLIENTS%) do (
  SET client=%%x
  echo !client!;
  if "%1"=="!client!" goto end
  )
:end
```

Note that the variable is referenced with an slightly different syntax `!client!` instead of `%client%`. *Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at execution time.*

Comment: I used the code above, however, when I provided blah1 as arg1, it still couldn't match the condition.

Comment: @VictorW - that is because the left side of the comparison is quoted, and the right side is not. The line should read `if "%~1"=="!client!" goto end`